# How to book many marines quickly

Tags: starcraft-2

In the late game, when I have 5-7 raxes I often need to book 15-20 marines (lings, etc) at a time. To do so right now I'm pressing 'a' button 15-20 times... which take me solid 5-10 seconds....

Is there any way to do that quicker? I believe I can configure my Windows to do 'auto-repeat' with SMALL delay, but I will need to do that before starting playing starcraft and change settings back once I left.

Is there any better way?

Comment: it has been some time, but can't you just select all of the barracks and then press your marine button 5 times to que up 5 marines PER barracks?

Comment: Sure I can, but if I have reactors o 3 raxes + 3 other raxes with tech lab, then i can build 6 rines and 3 marauders. so i need to hit that 9 times. Plus sometimes you want to book not 9, but 12-16 ... and if you have 9 raxes ... that even become worse....

Comment: I'm just wondering, may be there is a trick same to what protoss has: during warp in they hit 'X' (or whatever they define) and zealots spawn as they move mouse... which is almost instant even though protoss has 12 warp-gates

Comment: @Ender No, that's not how it works. Each button press builds 1 unit, period, not one unit per building.

Comment: 2Decency: Have you played Protoss? Do you know how do they wrap units? They can wrap zealots (or whatever other gateway units - only 1 type though) just by pressing (and keeping) "wrap" button and moving mouse

Comment: You can press and hold your Marine button just as easily as a toss player can press and hold their Stalker button. It's exactly the same... except they have to click too if they are warping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to modify your autorepeat settings and then simply hold down the key for an appropriate duration. This is the only way I'm aware of, as StarCraft doesn't allow you to configure that setting in-game.

In Windows, these two settings are in Keyboard Properties --> Speed --> Repeat Delay/Refresh Rate.

Protoss players have gotten pretty good at moving the mouse at an appropriate speed that matches the refresh rate of the keypress so as to warp in units quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use an external source, this is not possible within the game of StarCraft.

Protoss can't warp in 15 stalkers to a pylon with a push of a button, Zerg can't make 20 roaches from larva with a push of a button, and Terran can't queue up 10 marines with a push of a button.

If you want to do it the fastest way, this is what I do. I have all my barracks on hotkey 2. I hit 2. I hold in A. If it looks like I have AROUND 10 marines, I let it go. If I look over, I hit ESC a couple of times to get it to a close number.

I will pretty much always choose to have 1 or 2 off and save a couple of seconds than to get the exact number of units and waste valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can hold shift and click the marine to que 5 at a time

Comment: Can you confirm if that's really the case? There are two answers conflicting with your guess